# Initialize const variable in constructor after changing it

Tags: c++

I have a Client class, which receives an std::string variable called emailAdress. This is what the code looks like now, and it works:

```
private:
    const std::string email;

Client::Client(std::string emailAddress) : email{emailAddress}
{

}
```

Now, I want to check if the email contains characters like an @ or a valid name with no strange characters. I want to do this with regex.
Now, my question is, **how do I initialize the *const std::string email* variable after changing the parameter variable?** It says it doesn't want to because it is a const variable, that is why it is in the initialization list of the constructor right now.

Comment: If you need to change it then why is it const?

Comment: It doesn't need to get changed later on, it should be initialized in the constructor and then be const

Comment: `email{SomeFunctionThatPerformsNecessaryChanges(emailAddress)}`?

Comment: Ooooh that makes so much sense thank you!!

Comment: `const` data members come with several drawbacks and are generally not worth it. It almost always makes the type non-assignable and non-moveable. It is often best to maintain the invariance using the class interface. Make the member `private` and don't provide a setter.

Comment: Once you are in the constructor, you might be too late. Have the checking in a function that can return a lack of `Client`

Comment: @ François Andrieux, I will keep this in mind thank you! This is however from an exam example for school so I thought it would be good to know how to do it anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the parameter to a function, and let the function return the modified string.

```
class Client {
private:
    const std::string email;
    static std::string validateEmail(std::string email) {
        // ...
        return modifiedEmail;
    }

public:
    Client::Client(std::string emailAddress) : email{validateEmail(std::move(emailAddress))}
    {

    }
};
```